# Confidential phone recording ended up in my voicemail - how?

Tags: privacy, iphone

I received a voicemail on my iPhone of a recording from an organization I am not in any way affiliated with. The voicemail is a recording of the organization's representative and another party with respect to possible services. It is suppose to be confidential and one of the party's is a little nervous about giving permission. They representative assures the person this is confidential, but here it is on my phone?!

The phone number of the organization appears to be legit per a google search. My understanding of business phone systems is that they do not allow for something like this to happen, however, maybe with some kinds of systems the user has to enter a phone number, or ???  and thus this was misdirected to me.

Questions:

1)  How can an unknown third party, end up with a recording between two other parties and a confidential recording at that?

2)  How secure are such recording systems? It concerns me that such system could be so easily "misdirected"?

3)  Anything else that I might consider or need to know?

Research:

- I've done an internet search to see if other's have experienced this
  issue and I must not be using the correct key words because I've come
  up with nothing.
- Called my cell phone carrier who assured me my phone was okay, and
  thinks this is a one-off and simply a misdirected call.
- Spoke with another person who records confidential recordings in
  another industry and there appears no way that the person who
  recorded the call could misdirect it using the particular system they
  have at their disposal.

Comment: I've actually seen a similar claim (through reddit) just a few days ago. A voicemail system with an iOS app (unfortunately not named) was supposed to have the same issue. I would bet there's a bug in the server handling access to recordings that makes some files available to more accounts than it should. There's an endless number of possible mechanisms that could cause it, and you would have to contact the provider of the voicemail system to get it resolved.

Comment: Natanael and all, Interesting.  In my case I don't think the incident I describe has anything to do with my iPhone - it could have been any type of phone. I have no recording app. The confidential recording just landed in my voicemail. 

Is it possible to share a couple scenarios that might allow this to happen.  It just piques my curiosity. 

I've found little on the internet that addresses it.